# Prevent ts files from being sent

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am using node JS with Angular-CLI, and I saw my .ts files are being sent to the client via HTTP. for example `http://localhost/main.ts` will send user my main.ts files.

As I understand it, ts is being transpiled into js file before sent to browser, am I correct? If it is so, how can I prevent .ts being sent, and make server only send .js files?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **TL;DR**: Try run the project with `ng serve -prod --aot`

---

For an Angular-cli project.. when you are done with development and you are finally ready for realworld users to use your app, you should run `ng build -prod --aot` in the root of your project.. This will create the `dist` directory in your project root containing the *actual* final javascript files and html assets that are meant to be served to users via regular HTTP (using a production webserver such as e.g. [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) or apache). Note that there will be no `.ts` files in inside this final `dist` directory.

Adding -prod flag ensures that it will be optimized for production .
The --aot flag is for [Ahead of Time compilation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html).